# Rewrite Query String in Wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to rewrite a query string in Wordpress within the **functions.php** file, but it just isn't working. I'm probably making some dumb mistake, so any guidance is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to rewrite this URL: `www.domain.com/car-lease-rate/?term1=true` to `www.domain.com/car-lease-rate/term1`... or if possible `www.domain.com/car-lease-rate/term/1`.

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite');
function add_my_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^car-lease-rate/term/([^/]+)','index.php?term1=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Comment: I don't have very much experience with Wordpress. But I see in admin dashboard, there is a section to config permalinks. You can see here http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: @MinhQuý It will rewrite posts, pages, tags, categories, ect. But nothing beyond that (as far as I know). The add_rewrite_rule function exists to cover that, but I just can't get the regular expression to work!

Comment: Rewrites is still a bit of a mistery for me, on tip I can give you though, remember, you have to flush your rewrites after every change for them to take affect

Answer (score 1):

You can try my code. I don't test it :p

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrite');
function add_my_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^car-lease-rate/term1/([^/]*)/?','index.php/car-lease-rate?term1=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Comment: So sad! This's first times I code with Wordpress so I can't help you. Here's document http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule that I read